# Understanding KnapsackSolve

Tags: mathematical-optimization, combinatorics

I was playing around with the new [`KnapsackSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/KnapsackSolve.html) function in *Mathematica* 11 and came across something odd that I don't understand. Perhaps someone could shed some light on this for me. Here's my dataset:

```
data = <|"two" -> {1, 2, 1}, "three" -> {1, 3, 1}, "four" -> {1, 4, 1}|>
```

When I call `KnapsackSolve` for various target values:

```
KnapsackSolve[data,2]
<|"two" -> 1, "three" -> 0, "four" -> 0|>
KnapsackSolve[data,3]
<|"two" -> 1, "three" -> 0, "four" -> 0|>
KnapsackSolve[data,4]
<|"two" -> 0, "three" -> 1, "four" -> 0|>
KnapsackSolve[data,5]
<|"two" -> 1, "three" -> 1, "four" -> 0|>
```

I was expecting 2 to give "two" - correct but 3 and 4 give unexpected answers, then 5 gives me "two" and "three".

I've set the costs to be all maxcounts all be to 1 and payoffs to be 1 also.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are trying to maximize `c1+c2+c3` subject to `2c1+3c2+4c2<=n`, where all variables are either `0` or `1`.

For `n=2` there is only one answer, `c1=1,c2=0,c3=0`.

For `n=3` there are two answers, `c1=1,c2=0,c3=0` as given, or `c1=0,c2=1,c3=0`.

For `n=4` there are three answers, `c1=0,c2=1,c3=0` as given, or `c1=1,c2=0,c3=0`, or `c1=0,c2=0,c3=1`.

For `n=5` there is only one answer `c1=1,c2=1,c3=0`.

Comment: I understand, so I'm only getting the first answer back that fulfils the criteria rather than the complete set of answers then.
It's not clear from the documentation that all results are not returned - but then again all of the examples only return a single set!